# How to insert possible dates between an given date range in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table name Event having two column Start date and End date

### Event

- Start_Date  :2014-01-10
- End_Date    :2014-01-12

And another table Possible_Dates having a column Date_Val , i need to create a query which will insert all possible dates  between Event table's in this table's Start_Date and End_Date in Possible_Dates

### Possible_Dates

Date_Val

- 2014-01-10
- 2014-01-11
- 2014-01-12

Comment: Duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates for answer.

Comment: I need to create Query not Stored Proc.

Comment: There is an answer with select and insert as well.

Comment: The solution of insert is not as per my question because conditional dates are not inserting over there