# Recursive table to create a "calendar" temporary table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, recursion

I would like to create a temporary table in MySQL which would return 365 rows, each for all 365 days which preceded today.

In SQL Server I would do this:

```
with
dates as (SELECT dateadd(day,-365,cast(getdate() as date)) as daten union all select dateadd(day,+1,daten) from dates where daten<dateadd(day,-1,getdate()))

select * from dates

option(maxrecursion 0)
```

Is there a way to obtain something similar in MySQL?

Thank you.

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates

Comment: I might also recommend persisting this calendar table so that you don't have to waste the CPU every time to construct the table a new in memory (minimal though it is, in this particular case).