# Group by doesnt return "0"

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Im making a `SELECT` query for **two** tables.

Tables:

- ec_events
- ec_calendar

[image]

Select QUERY:

```
SELECT MONTH(`ec_calendar`.`Day`) AS Month ,COUNT(`ID_Event`) AS Count 
FROM `ec_events`,`ec_calendar` 
WHERE `ec_events`.`FK_Day`=`ec_calendar`.`ID_Day` AND YEAR(`ec_calendar`.`Day`) = 2015 
GROUP BY MONTH(`ec_calendar`.`Day`)
```

And the result:

[image]

The only problem here is May (5. month). On the result image you can see, that was ignored, because in `ec_calendar` is no entry for this month. Many times better will be, if 0 could be returned. So the table will loks so:

```
....
3  15
4  7
5  0
6  10
7  3
...
```

Is there any way to provide it?

Comment: what is `ec_calendar` table ?

Comment: The right one, with `ID_Day` and `Day` colums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a table `allMonth` with all months from 1..12, maybe you also will add year field if need it.

This **[sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates)** will give you an idea of fill the table with date ranges

**allMonth**

```
 month_id
 year_id
 name
```

Query

```
SELECT AM.month_id AS Month, COUNT(`ID_Event`) AS Count 
FROM  allMonth  AM
LEFT JOIN `ec_calendar` EC
       ON AM.month_id = MONTH(EC.`Day`)
INNER JOIN `ec_events`  EV
       ON EV.`FK_Day`= EC.`ID_Day`
      AND YEAR(EC.`Day`) = 2015 
GROUP BY AM.month_id
```

Aditional TIPS:

- Always try to use alias to improve reading
- Learn how to use explicit join syntax. Aaron Bertrand did some [**writting**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it

Comment: I dont think, that make another table is good solution. Here must be simplier way, but thanks for your time and answer.

Comment: @Bullman, Sorry but there isnt. I have answer this same question multiple times. With users missing `years`. `months` or  `days` In all cases the answer is create a table. And use the store procedure I include to fill the table.

Comment: For example include a table with `100` years of days  have only `36,500` so is very small, And believe me I did the math and isnt expensive neither on time executions. A table of months have only `1200 rows`

Comment: @Bullman think about it. How would you group something when isnt there?

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp):

```
SELECT MONTH(`ec_calendar`.`Day`) AS Month ,COUNT(`ID_Event`) AS Count 
FROM `ec_events`
LEFT JOIN `ec_calendar` 
ON `ec_events`.`FK_Day`=`ec_calendar`.`ID_Day` 
WHERE YEAR(`ec_calendar`.`Day`) = 2015 
GROUP BY MONTH(`ec_calendar`.`Day`)
```

A `LEFT JOIN` will keep all records from your left table and fill in `NULL`s where it doesn't match to your right table.

Comment: This wont work because your left side doesnt have a month `5`, you need an aditional `allMonths` table

Comment: Right idea.  Wrong order for the tables in the `from` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How changing the order will solve this? Right side doesnt have month 5 neither. In the sample is one but for `2016-05-28`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . You want everything in `ec_calendar` in order to get days with zero events.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Now I may be wrong but to me looks like `ec_calendar` has some holes. And `MONTH(ec_calendar.Day)` not will bring all months?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . It would seem odd to me that a table called `calendar` would be missing days.  Admittedly, the sample with a handful of random dates doesn't provide much information on what the table really contains, so you might be right.