# How to count rows each month of each year even a month is not present

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count the rows of each month of each year (there're a few years in a table) without skipping the empty month. Saying my table has some month without the data in it. Like 1,2,5,6,7,11,12 (3,4,8,9,10 is missing). But I don't want the output skip it - just put 0 instead.

I come up with this code but it skipping the empty record.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(`log_datetime`) as year,MONTH(`log_datetime`) AS mon,
    count(log_id) AS count
FROM
    log_db
GROUP BY
    MONTH (`log_datetime`),
    YEAR (`log_datetime`)
ORDER BY
    YEAR (`log_datetime`) DESC,
    MONTH (`log_datetime`) DESC
```

What I expect is:

```
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 12 | 100 |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 11 | 120 |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 10 |  0  |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 09 |  0  |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 08 |  0  |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 07 | 123 |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 06 | 200 |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 05 | 250 |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 04 |  0  |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 03 |  0  |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 02 | 211 |
+------+----+-----+
| 2015 | 01 | 200 |
+------+----+-----+
```

Comment: You need a calendar or tally table as the base table for your query. Also, you really should only tag the DBMS you are using. mysql <> sql server.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the idea. Could you please give me a deeper explanation?

Comment: sql cannot pad missing data in the table. You need to create a table with all the `YEAR` and `MONTH` in it. The use that table as `LEFT JOIN` .

Comment: Just handle the missing results in PHP - with a simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `calendar` table to do this.

```
SELECT c.years,
       c.months, 
       Count(log_id) AS count 
FROM   calendar_table C 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN log_db l 
                    ON c.months = Month (`log_datetime`) 
                       AND c.years = Year (`log_datetime`) 
GROUP  BY c.years, 
          c.months 
ORDER  BY c.months DESC, 
          c.years DESC
```

Refer the below links to generate calendar table

1. [How to populate a table with a range of dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates)
2. https://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables
3. https://gist.github.com/bryhal/4129042

Comment: I created a `calendar_table` and run your code. But the server returns nothing. No error nor result :(

Comment: The code is exactly as you gave me. But I changed some variables name according to the table column.

Comment: @Wilf - Did you populate calendar table with data

Comment: When you have data in `calendar` table am sure the query will return data unless you put some `log_db` table filter in where condition

Comment: It works but it says `Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 372 total, Query took 54.3462 sec)`. Any way to make it faster?

Comment: Filter the calendar table between the date  range you need to show

Answer (score 0):

Create a calendar table and do a left join with log_db table.