# laravel query builder with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, chart.js

I am implementing a query to draw a multiple line chart using chartjs. I have an array of dates

```
["2016-10-16","2016-10-17","2016-10-18","2016-10-19","2016-10-20","2016-10-21","2016-10-22","2016-10-23","2016-10-24","2016-10-25","2016-10-26","2016-10-27","2016-10-28","2016-10-29","2016-10-30","2016-10-31","2016-11-01","2016-11-02","2016-11-03","2016-11-04","2016-11-05","2016-11-06","2016-11-07","2016-11-08","2016-11-09","2016-11-10","2016-11-11","2016-11-12","2016-11-13","2016-11-14","2016-11-15","2016-11-16"]
```

This array has dates between "2016-11-16" and "2016-10-16".

I have created a model `Tickets`, and I wrote a query to fetch tickets count grouped by `tickets.status`.

```
$join = $this->tickets();
$tickets = $join
         ->when($category, function($query) use ($category) {
             $ranges = $this->dateRange($category);
             return $query->whereBetween('tickets.created_at', $ranges);
         })
         ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(tickets.id) as tickets'), 'ticket_status.name as name', 'tickets.created_at')
         ->groupBy('ticket_status.name', 'tickets.created_at')
         ->get();
```

Executing this query I got

```
[
    {
        "tickets":"1",
        "name":"Closed",
        "created_at":"2016-11-08 14:07:32"
    },
    {
        "tickets":"1",
        "name":"Open",
        "created_at":"2016-11-08 14:07:32"
    },
    {
        "tickets":"1",
        "name":"Open",
        "created_at":"2016-11-11 12:24:39"
    },
    {
        "tickets":"1",
        "name":"Open",
        "created_at":"2016-11-11 12:26:38"
    },
    {
        "tickets":"1",
        "name":"Open",
        "created_at":"2016-11-11 12:27:04"
    },
    {
        "tickets":"1",
        "name":"Open",
        "created_at":"2016-11-11 12:27:49"
    },
    {
        "tickets":"1",
        "name":"Open",
        "created_at":"2016-11-11 12:28:47"
    },
    {
        "tickets":"1",
        "name":"Resolved",
        "created_at":"2016-11-08 14:07:32"
    }
]
```

If `$label[0] != $tickets.created`, ticket and name will be null but should have date

Please help me to get output like

```
[
    [
        'tickets'=>0,
        'name'=>null,//tickets don't have this date
        'created_at'=>'2016-10-16'
    ],
    [
        'tickets'=>0,
        'name'=>null,//tickets don't have this date
        'created_at'=>'2016-10-15'
    ],
    [
        'tickets'=>1,
        'name'=>'closed',//on this date 1 closed ticket
        'created_at'=>'2016-10-14'
    ],
    [
        'tickets'=>3,
        'name'=>'open',//on this date 3 open ticket
        'created_at'=>'2016-10-14'
    ],
    [
        'tickets'=>2,
        'name'=>'resolved',//on this date 2 resolved ticket
        'created_at'=>'2016-10-14'// on 2016-10-14 has three different tickets
    ],
    ...........
]
```

Please help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to go trough your dates and then search for all the tickets that match those date.

Comment: You can use `FORMAT(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD')` in your SQL also and then something like : `array_search($date, array_column($tickets, 'created_at'));`

Answer (score 2):

Follow please [Laravel:Collection:GroupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-groupby)

So it's maybe you need to have a code look like this

```
$join = $this->tickets();
$tickets = $join
         ->when($category, function($query) use ($category) {
             $ranges = $this->dateRange($category);
             return $query->whereBetween('tickets.created_at', $ranges);
         })
         ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(tickets.id) as tickets'), 'ticket_status.name as name', 'tickets.created_at')
         ->get()->groupBy(/** YOUR LOGIC HERE  **/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert this to Laravel/Eloquent, but this is a raw db query that does what you're looking for.

Assumed Tables / Data

```
Table: tbl_dates
id | date
1    2016-11-17 00:00:00
2    2016-11-18 00:00:00
...etc...

Table: tickets
id | created_at
1    2016-11-18 12:34:56
2    2016-11-18 01:23:45
3    2016-11-18 02:34:56

Table: ticket_status
ticket_id | name
1           Open
2           Closed
3           Closed
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(tickets.id) AS tickets,
  ticket_status.name, 
  DATE(tbl_dates.date) AS ticket_date
FROM 
  tbl_dates
LEFT JOIN 
  tickets 
ON
  (DATE(tbl_dates.date) = DATE(tickets.created_at))
LEFT JOIN
  ticket_status
ON
  (tickets.id = ticket_status.ticket_id)
GROUP BY 
  ticket_status.name
ORDER BY 
  ticket_date
ASC
```

Result:

```
 tickets | name | ticket_date
 0         NULL   2016-11-17
 1         Open   2016-11-18
 2         Closed 2016-11-18
```

Basically, to do this in pure MySQL you need a table with all dates. [Check out this SO post for an easy way to generate the dates table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL's [date function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to format the date first and then group by the formatted date:

So your query should look something like this:

```
$join = $this->tickets();
    $tickets = $join
            ->when($category, function($query) use ($category) {
                $ranges = $this->dateRange($category);
                return $query->whereBetween('tickets.created_at', $ranges);
            })
            ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(tickets.id) as tickets'), 'ticket_status.name as name', DB::raw('DATE('tickets.created_at') as created_date'))
            ->groupBy('ticket_status.name', 'created_date')
            ->get();
```