# MYSQL pass a date variable and print all the date within that week

Tags: mysql

How to write the query in mysql where i pass a date variable, it can list down all the date within that week.

etc. if i pass date = 6-12-2016, 
the query will print:

```
  date
 4-12-2016
 5-12-2016
 6-12-2016
 7-12-2016
 8-12-2016
 9-12-2016
10-12-2016
```

Comment: where to start? Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a **Calendar Table** like on this SO question:

- [How to populate a table with a range of dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates)

And then run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM calendar_table
WHERE WEEK(date_column, 0) = WEEK('2016-12-06', 0);
```

This will produce output you want. 0 number in the argument describe mode in WEEK function. You can change the number to another number according to your needs. See [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) about WEEK function.