# Get sunday date between two date and last day from one month mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I want to get all sunday date between two dates and get last day between two date, how can i do that in mysql?
Example :

```
start date | end date
2017-03-01 | 2017-03-31
```

then the results are :

```
2017-03-05
2017-03-12
2017-03-19
2017-03-26
2017-03-31
```

Start date and end date possible to change, please advise me. 
Thank you

Comment: If you are still having problem, then update your question, rather than dropping random comments below.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a [DAYOFWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function which would return `1` for any date which is a Sunday:

```
SELECT date_column
FROM yourTable
WHERE (date_column BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-03-31' AND
       DAYOFWEEK(date_column) = 1) OR        -- any Sunday
      date_column = '2017-03-31'             -- or the last date in the range
```

I am assuming that `yourTable` already has dates in it.  If you need help with populating a table with a range of dates, this problem has been covered well before on Stack Overflow, q.v. here:

[How to populate a table with a range of dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates)

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: This assumes that all the dates are also in the table. Would be nice if he DOES have another table that has all the dates.

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno If he doesn't have any date data to begin with, then he should be asking about how to generate a calendar table.

Comment: I assume that his table does not really have all the dates as per his given example; his example has a start date and end date in the same row. It's possible he's fine with accepting answers that are also procedures/batch statements? Could maybe generate a temp calendar table (or even a permanent one)

Comment: Hi @BennjoeMordeno, just like Tim said. I don't have table date in mysql, the start date and end date just choose by user.

Comment: @MasHarjo Then generate a calendar table to get your dates.  A database might not be the fastest way to get this information, assuming you don't even have any tables at all setup.

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno, please see my answers that the problem i face now

Comment: Hi @BennjoeMordeno please see at this question Thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108682/get-sunday-date-between-two-date-and-last-day-from-one-month-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Since you now mentioned that you don't have a table for the dates, you could approach it like this if you don't want to add a generic calendar table on your database.

```
declare @startdate datetime 
declare @enddate datetime
DECLARE @startdateLoop datetime

select @startdate = CAST(start as DATE), @enddate = CAST(end_date as DATE) from #t
set @startdateLoop = @startdate
CREATE TABLE #tempCal
  (dates datetime)

  WHILE @startdateLoop != @enddate 
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #tempCal
  SELECT @startdateLoop

  SET @startdateLoop = DATEADD(dd, 1, @startdateLoop)
  END

  SELECT * FROM #tempCal
  WHERE dates between @startdate and @enddate and DAYOFWEEK(dates) = 1
```

You may turn this into a procedure if you want to.

Would still be nice if you DO HAVE a calendar table; as Tim has suggested.

Comment: Ok, let me try :D

Comment: Please don't have a discussion under my answer.

Comment: Ok @TimBiegeleisen Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT calender FROM calender WHERE calender.calender >='2017-03-01' AND calender.calender <='2017-03-31'  AND DAYOFWEEK(calender) = 1 OR calender = '2017-03-31' Group By calender
```

This is @Tim Answer
Thanks Tim