# populating a table with dates MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to populate my table "MyDates" with  a range of dates as shown in the code below. When I run the code I get this error "Unknown system variable 'dateStart'"

```
DECLARE
     dateStart  DATE   DEFAULT '2011-01-01';
DECLARE
     dateEnd DATE   DEFAULT'2011-12-31';
WHILE dateStart<=dateEnd DO
INSERT
     INTO
          MyDates
          (
               mydate
          )
          VALUES
          (
               dateStart
          ) ;
SET dateStart=date_add(dateStart,INTERVAL 1 DAY) ;
END WHILE;
END;
```

Comment: Try adding the code inside a mysql function, then call the function.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the procedure body. It should work. Also show your SP signature.

Comment: I think it is you attempting to include defaults that is the problem. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates which appears to be the source of your code, but it does not have default values. *Not sure if MySQL allows this yet.* also see http://rextester.com/CSLKE1780