# Select used days from multiple date ranges (events)

Tags: mysql

I have database with multiple evens.

```
StartDate      EndDate
-----------------------------
2017-03-18     2017-03-20
2017-10-10     2017-10-10
2017-11-30     2017-12-01
```

What I need is to get list of used dates which should look like:

```
2017-03-18
2017-03-19
2017-03-20
2017-10-10
2017-11-30
2017-12-01
```

These events may be quite a lot and they might be overlapping so the query must be very quick and records grouped by date. If it would be quickier to select unused days it doesn't matter. I just need to find out which days in current year are used.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support analytic functions, so doing this natively isn't straightforward.  However, it often isn't necessary—on fetching each row in the resultset, your application can loop between `StartDate` and `EndDate` to construct the desired list of "used days".

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by making yourself a `dates` table with a row for every day in it.

Then you can do this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT d.day
   FROM dates d
   JOIN mytable t ON d.day >= t.StartDate AND d.day <= t.EndDate
  ORDER BY d.day
```

and get an enumeration of all the days, meeting your need.

There are ways to generate the `dates` table on the fly, but they are a notorious pain in the neck. You might want to look up that sort of thing.

(Shameless self-promo ... here's a possible way to do it. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/)

Comment: [how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates)