# Select row for each date in range

Tags: mysql

I have a **table** which has `personIds`, a start **date** and an end **date**.

I need to select each `personId-date` pair, but the dates are in a range specified by two **columns**.

For example:

```
personId | startDate | endDate
1 | 2018-05-10 | 2018-05-13
```

would return

```
personId | date
1 | 2018-05-10
1 | 2018-05-11
1 | 2018-05-12
1 | 2018-05-13
```

Answer (score 0):

One option here would be to create a calendar table containing all the dates, inclusive, for 2018 (and possibly other years as well).  Then, just inner join this calendar table to the record for a given person.

```
SELECT c.date
FROM calendar c
INNER JOIN yourTable t
    ON c.date BETWEEN t.startDate AND t.endDate;
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates) for some good options on creating a calendar table in MySQL.

Comment: Anyway to avoid using a calendar table? My database has dates going back many years.

Comment: Yes, you might be able to handle it using dynamic SQL.  But even then you would be generating the data, I think.