# Get number of monday in a rangedate mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Get number of monday in a rangedate MySQL, I run this code but it give me result 0:

```
select count(*) from tarif where weekday(`end_tarif`<= '2019-02-21'AND `start_tarif`>='2019-02-05') = 0;
```

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tarif` (                  
    `tarif_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `start_tarif` date NOT NULL,
    `end_tarif` date NOT NULL,
    `day_tarif` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`tarif_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `tarif` VALUES (1, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', '10'),
    (2, '2019-02-11', '2019-02-20', '20'),
    (3, '2019-02-21', '2019-02-28', '10'),
    (4, '2019-03-01', '2019-02-10', '15');
```

Comment: A calendar help table would be handy.

Comment: im having confusion understanding the question. You want to list mondays which lie in the range?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

Comment: i want the number of monday includes in the range '2019-02-5' -'2019-02-21'

Comment: `WEEKDAY()` works with only single (date) argument

Comment: You mean you want to know how many Mondays there are between those dates?

Comment: So what's the point of the table?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @ Strawberry,i wont get  the result only if thedaterange is include between start_tarif andend_tarif in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a solution using a calendar table. So you can use a solution like the following:

**1. create a table with calendar data**

```
-- create the table "calendar"
CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
  `dateValue` DATE
);

-- insert the days to the table "calendar"
INSERT INTO calendar
SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date from
    (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
    (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
    (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
    (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
    (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
HAVING gen_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
```

> You can find the script to generate the calendar data [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992247/3840840):
>   [How to populate a table with a range of dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates)

**2. create the table with your data (with monday tarif)**

```
-- create the table "tarif"
CREATE TABLE tarif (
  tarif_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  start_tarif DATE NOT NULL,
  end_tarif DATE NOT NULL,
  day_tarif VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  monday_tarif VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (tarif_id)
);

-- insert the tarif information
INSERT INTO tarif VALUES 
  (1, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', '10', '5'),
  (2, '2019-02-11', '2019-02-20', '20', '5'),
  (3, '2019-02-21', '2019-02-28', '10', '5'),
  (4, '2019-03-01', '2019-02-10', '15', '5');
```

**Note:** To create a useful example I added the column `monday_tarif` and insert the value 5 on every date range.

**3. get the result**

Now you can get all days of your needed range (between 2019-02-05 and 2019-02-21) from the calendar table. With a `LEFT JOIN` you add your tarif table to all days of date range.

With a `CASE WHEN` and the condition `DAYOFWEEK = 2` or `DAYNAME = 'Monday'` you can check if the current date is a Monday or not, to get the correct tarif value of the day.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(cal.dateValue) = 2 THEN tarif.monday_tarif ELSE tarif.day_tarif END) AS sumWithMondayTarif 
FROM calendar cal
    LEFT JOIN tarif ON cal.dateValue BETWEEN start_tarif AND end_tarif
WHERE cal.dateValue BETWEEN '2019-02-05' AND '2019-02-21';
```

---

You can also use a `SELECT` with a sub select of the calendar:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(cal.dateValue) = 2 THEN tarif.monday_tarif ELSE tarif.day_tarif END) AS sumWithMondayTarif FROM (
  SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) dateValue FROM
    (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
    (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
    (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
    (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
    (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
  HAVING dateValue BETWEEN '2019-02-05' AND '2019-02-21'
) cal LEFT JOIN tarif ON cal.dateValue BETWEEN start_tarif AND end_tarif
```

---

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a484225f87a46ad18014dccf987349bc)

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned query is for `sundays` count. you can modify it as per your requirement

```
select ROUND((
      (unix_timestamp(`end_tarif`) - unix_timestamp(`start_tarif`) )/(24*60*60)
      -7+WEEKDAY(`start_tarif`)-WEEKDAY(`end_tarif`)
    )/7)

 + if(WEEKDAY(`start_tarif`) <= 6, 1, 0)
 + if(WEEKDAY(`end_tarif`) >= 6, 1, 0) as Sunday
from tarif 
where  `end_tarif`<= '2019-02-21' AND `start_tarif`>='2019-02-05'  ;
```