# Identify count of days in a date range

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am very much new to the mysql and sincere apologies as struggling to find the right approach for the question.

I have a table which is containing the events schedule time:

[image]

Event_id 1 will be running on every Monday in between 03-04-2022 to 03-12-2022.I need to find the total run count of the each Event_id in between a date range.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get number of monday in a rangedate mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569956/get-number-of-monday-in-a-rangedate-mysql)

Comment: how i can find the number of mondays/tuesday/wednesday.. in a date range

Answer (score 0):

You need to find number of day between start and end date.
E.g. how many Monday between start and end date for event_id=1 and so on.

In the question start_date and end_date for event_id=4 are not correct as start_date > end_date.
Also, there is a spelling mistake in day name for evnet_id=4.

The query used for getting the result, after fixing data issues is -

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
date_gen (gen_dt) AS
(
SELECT min(start_date) from event_tab
union all
SELECT date_add(gen_dt,interval 1 day) from date_gen where gen_dt < (select max(end_date) from event_tab)
)
SELECT 
e.event_id,
sum(case when dayname(d.gen_dt) =  e.schedule_day then 1 else 0 end ) day_nos_as_run_count
FROM date_gen d, event_tab e
where 
cast(d.gen_dt as date) between e.start_date and e.end_date
group by e.event_id
```

DB fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/316vpuirZGRw1aHLyBnsSb/0).

Recursive query example help from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-recursive-cte-common-table-expressions/).

Sample output -

| event_id | day_nos_as_run_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 35 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 |

Another variant of the query -

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
date_gen (gen_dt) AS
(
SELECT min(start_date) from event_tab
union all
SELECT date_add(gen_dt,interval 1 day) from date_gen where gen_dt < (select max(end_date) from event_tab)
)
SELECT 
e.event_id,
count(d.gen_dt)
FROM event_tab e left join date_gen d
on ( cast(d.gen_dt as date) between e.start_date and e.end_date
and e.schedule_day = dayname(d.gen_dt))
group by e.event_id
order by e.event_id
```

Comment: thanks much @pankaj,yes this is the question how i can find the number of mondays/tuesday/wednesdat.. in a date range.
It seems data is correct for event_id = 4 because date range is of one year 09-09-2022 to 08-09-2023

Answer (score 0):

Start by storing dates in date format:  `03-04-2022` should be stored as `2022-04-03` (assuming that your format is day-month-year).  And store into a column declared to be `DATE`, not `VARCHAR`.

Then you have the ability to use the `DATEDIFF()` function to get differences.