# SQL - sum column for every date

Tags: sql, sql-server

This seemed like a very easy thing to do but I got stuck. I have a query like this:

```
select op.date, count(p.numberofoutstanding)
from people p
left join outstandingpunches op
on p.fullname = op.fullname
group by op.date
```

That outputs a table like this:

[image]

How can I sum over the dates so the sum for each row is equal to the sums up to that date? For example, the first column would be 27, the second would be 27 + 4, the third 27 + 4 + 11, etc.

I encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218902/the-sql-over-clause-when-and-why-is-it-useful) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352963/sql-sum-amount-for-each-date) question, and I saw people are using `OVER` in their queries for this, but I'm confused by what do I have to partition. I tried partitioning by date but it's giving me incorrect results.

Comment: You don't have to use partitioning if you don't need to, it is optional. Partition By will effectively scope the records into a windowed subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum.  This looks like:

```
select op.date, count(*),
       sum(count(*)) over (order by op.date) as running_count
from people p join
     outstandingpunches op
     on p.fullname = op.fullname
group by op.date;
```

Note:  I changed the `join` from a `left join` to an inner join.  You are aggregating by a column in the second table.  Your results have no examples of a `NULL` date column and that doesn't seem useful.  Hence, it seems that rows are assumed to match.

Comment: You need `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` to ensure correct results, and for performance

Comment: @Charlieface . . . The default is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.  The `ORDER BY` key is unique because of the `GROUP BY`, so your comment is simply wrong.

Comment: Yes in this instance you are using a unique key, but I've seen so many examples where that is not the case that I would say *always* write it just out of principle. And the performance argument stands: as far as I am aware there is no logical in the compiler currently to optimize that case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use sum and not count.

```
select o.date_c, 
       sum(sum(p.numberofoutstanding)) over (order by o.date_c)
from people p 
left join outstandingpunches o on p.fullname = o.fullname
group by o.date_c;
```

Here is a small demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ca5ef0ec90c1adf3e731c5c8f4cda52)

Have in mind that I have renamed your column date to date_c. I believe you should not use data types as column names.

Comment: Hi @lukaabra, can you please tell me how is a sum of a count the correct answer ? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. If I use sum of a sum I get much higher numbers than the actual case. My rows have the values: 71, 78, 99, etc., which is not correct.

Comment: And what about my demo, what is wrong with tat ? Can you correct it and send me the link after you correct it and run it ? Hvala. Here is the demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5cdfc9c8e0cead21b7fef346556a38b

Comment: Here is the corrected fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1e19ec47901d2b179733c4727e279ab

Using sum of sum gives out some wonky values

Comment: I understand now. Thanks!