# How to Get List of weeks between the given date range?

Tags: mysql

I want week list with week number, week start date and end date between two dates. Let me give you an example,

If I am passing start date as `2019-12-11` and end date as `2019-12-25`, then expected output should look like below:

```
Week Number | Week start date | Week end date

W1           2019-12-11       2019-12-14     
W2           2019-12-15       2019-12-21     
W3           2019-12-22       2019-12-25
```

I have tried using below query but I got output like

```
 Week start date | Week end date

 2019-12-15        2019-12-21     
 2019-12-22        2019-12-28
```

```
select start_date, date_add(start_date, INTERVAL 6 DAY) as end_date
from
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) start_date
from
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where start_date between '2019-12-11' and '2019-12-25'
AND date_format(start_date, '%w') = 0
```

Comment: An RDMS is for the storage and retrieval of data. I don't see how this relates to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`WEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function and [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```sql
-- calendar table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992247/3840840
SELECT CONCAT('W', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WEEK(start_date))) AS `Week Number`, 
  MIN(start_date) AS `Week start date`, MAX(start_date) AS `Week end date`
FROM (
  SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01', t4 * 10000 + t3 * 1000 + t2 * 100 + t1 * 10 + t0) AS start_date
  FROM
    (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
    (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
    (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
    (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
    (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4
) v
WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2019-12-11' AND '2019-12-25'
GROUP BY WEEK(start_date)
ORDER BY WEEK(start_date)
```

By using [`WEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) you don't have to calculate the weeks yourself. MySQL can detect the weeks. With [`WEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) you can get the week number of a date value. You can group by this week number to get the rows for every week. With `MIN` and `MAX` on the date value you get the first and last date of each week.

With [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) you can add a row number to your result. This function is available since MySQL 8.0. On earlier versions of MySQL you can use a solution like the following:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('W', @row_number:=@row_number+1) AS `Week Number`, 
  MIN(start_date) AS `Week start date`, MAX(start_date) AS `Week end date`
FROM (
  SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01', t4 * 10000 + t3 * 1000 + t2 * 100 + t1 * 10 + t0) AS start_date
  FROM
    (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
    (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
    (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
    (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
    (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4
  ORDER BY start_date
) v, (SELECT @row_number:=0) rn
WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2019-12-11' AND '2019-12-25'
GROUP BY WEEK(start_date)
ORDER BY WEEK(start_date)
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50d9f94c0f2e04ddafeda14b732ff5e0)

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of how this may solve OPs question, along with any assumptions (i.e. database version)