# Getting days extra when querying for room occupancy

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting extra days when querying for room occupancy. I think this is because it still does `SUM(DATEDIFF(...) +1)` even on days with two reservations. So for example in february it returns 31 days for a room.

How can i add one day except for days with two reservations, then it only has to +1 it for one of the two.

```sql
SELECT 
  room_id, 
  SUM(DATEDIFF(
    LEAST(end_time, '2019-12-31 23:59:59'),
    GREATEST(start_time, '2019-12-01 00:00:00')
  ) + 1) as days 
FROM reservations 
WHERE 
  (start_time >= '2019-12-01 00:00:00' AND start_time < '2020-01-01 00:00:00')
  OR
  (end_time >= '2019-12-01 00:00:00' AND end_time < '2020-01-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY room_id
```

Here's a fiddle that represents the unneeded extra day,
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ta53CprLisnRXh9A8wVwZv/1
it returns 7 days but the room is reserved for 5

Comment: This is not a complete question, because no premise or sample data has been given.  Please add this information to your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm sorry https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ta53CprLisnRXh9A8wVwZv/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45992247/3840840) to solve this:

```
SELECT 
  room_id, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT date_value)
FROM test INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01', t4 * 10000 + t3 * 1000 + t2 * 100 + t1 * 10 + t0) AS date_value
  FROM
    (SELECT 0 t0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
    (SELECT 0 t1 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
    (SELECT 0 t2 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
    (SELECT 0 t3 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
    (SELECT 0 t4 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4
  ) calendar ON calendar.date_value BETWEEN CAST(start_time AS DATE) AND CAST(end_time AS DATE)
WHERE 
  (start_time >= '2019-02-01 00:00:00' AND start_time < '2019-03-01 00:00:00')
  OR
  (end_time >= '2019-02-01 00:00:00' AND end_time < '2019-03-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY room_id;
```

The calendar table is a generated table with all days since 1970-01-01 as date value. You can join your table to the calendar table and count all distinct days matching your table.

[**demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ta53CprLisnRXh9A8wVwZv/2)

Comment: What is this magic, how does it work if i may ask? Where does the calendar table come from?

Comment: this returns crazy high amount of days on some rooms, weirdly

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald example data?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `+ 1` *before* doing the `SUM()` rather than afterwards.  If you fix the parentheses, then you will fix your problem:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(LEAST(end_time, '2019-03-01'),
                    GREATEST(start_time, '2019-02-01')
                   )
          ) + 1 as days 
FROM test 
WHERE start_time < '2019-03-01' AND
      end_time >= '2019-02-01'
GROUP BY room_id;
```

Notes about the date arithmetic.

I assume that you want rooms that are reserved for *any* part of February.  Your logic misses reservations that start in January and end in March.

Also, using time components with `datediff()` is counterintuitive.  That function only cares about the date.