# how to get the weeks b/w two dates as week1,week2,week3 in mysql

Tags: mysql

SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS xAxis,
        WEEK(created_at) AS yAxis
        FROM orders  WHERE created_at >= startDate
         AND created_at <= endDate GROUP BY WEEK(created_at);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just using `MIN` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(order_id) AS xAxis,
    WEEK(created_at) AS yAxis,
    MIN(created_at) AS week_start,
    MAX(created_at) AS week_end
FROM orders
WHERE
    created_at BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
GROUP BY
    WEEK(created_at);
```

The reasoning here is simple: the start of each week group of records should be the smallest date and vice-versa for the max.

Should your data not cover every day in the range, then you can join to a calendar table to bring in the missing dates.  The updated query would now look something like:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(o.order_id) AS xAxis,
    WEEK(t.dt) AS yAxis,
    MIN(t.dt) AS week_start,
    MAX(t.dt) AS week_end
FROM
(
    SELECT '2020-01-01' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020-01-02' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT '2020-12-31'
) t
LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON t.dt = o.created_at
WHERE
    o.created_at BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
GROUP BY
    WEEK(t.dt);
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates) for more information on generating date tables in MySQL.