# Filling Month and Year Gaps in Data

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table of date-based items, many of which have gaps between months and years. For example, if a post has been created in January, and five in April, I'll have gaps in Feb, March, May, and June. I've been scouring around and found that one thing to do is to use a numbers table, or create a temporary months table, and join off of that, but I still can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp_months (id INT unsigned PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO temp_months
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12);

SELECT
    COUNT(p.ID) AS COUNT,
    YEAR(p.created_date) as YEAR,
    tm.id as MONTH
FROM
    temp_months tm
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    my_table p
        ON
            MONTH(p.created_date) = tm.id
WHERE
    p.company_id = 123456
GROUP BY
    MONTH, YEAR
ORDER BY
    p.created_date DESC
```

This gives me the following format, with gaps (almost like I didn't join it to the temp table at all)

```
+-------+------+-------+
| COUNT | YEAR | MONTH |
+-------+------+-------+
|     1 | 2020 |     5 |
|     3 | 2020 |     2 |
|     1 | 2020 |     1 |
|     9 | 2019 |    10 |
|     2 | 2019 |     8 |
+-------+------+-------+
```

What I would *like* it to do, is fill in the gaps with an empty/null/0 `COUNT`, like:

```
+-------+------+-------+
| COUNT | YEAR | MONTH |
+-------+------+-------+
|  NULL | 2020 |     6 |
|     1 | 2020 |     5 |
|  NULL | 2020 |     4 |
|  NULL | 2020 |     3 |
|     3 | 2020 |     2 |
|     1 | 2020 |     1 |
|  NULL | 2019 |    12 |
|  NULL | 2019 |    11 |
|     9 | 2019 |    10 |
|  NULL | 2019 |     9 |
|     2 | 2019 |     8 |
|  NULL | 2019 |     7 |
+-------+------+-------+
```

I'm just not quite sure where I'm messing up.

Comment: @Nick I've got two setups, one running `10.3.14` and one running `10.3.23`

Comment: You need to move the `p.company_id = 123456` condition into the `JOIN` condition i.e. `LEFT OUTER JOIN
    my_table p
        ON
            MONTH(p.created_date) = tm.id AND
    p.company_id = 123456`

Comment: Fix that and you'll get close, you might still have an issue with getting the correct years.

Comment: I moved it in there and it's still giving me the same result

Comment: You removed the `WHERE` clause, right? Can you post some sample `my_table` data?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing your temp_months table to include year like so:

```
create table temp_months (yr int, mth int, primary key (yr, mth));
insert into temp_months values
(2020, 1), (2020, 2), (2020, 3), (2020, 4), (2020, 5), (2020, 6),
(2019, 7), (2019, 8), (2019, 9), (2019, 10), (2019, 11), (2019, 12);
```

Assuming your my_table was like so,

```
create table my_table (created_date date, company_id int, id int);
insert into my_table values
('2020-05-01', 123456, 1),
('2020-02-01', 123456, 1),('2020-02-01', 123456, 1),('2020-02-01', 123456, 1),
('2020-01-01', 123456, 1),
('2019-10-01', 123456, 1),('2019-10-01', 123456, 1),('2019-10-01', 123456, 1),('2019-10-01', 123456, 1),('2019-10-01', 123456, 1),('2019-10-01', 123456, 1),('2019-10-01', 123456, 1),('2019-10-01', 123456, 1),('2019-10-01', 123456, 1),
('2019-08-01', 123456, 1),('2019-08-01', 123456, 1);
```

You could run this kind of query:

```
select count(p.id), yr as year, mth as month
from temp_months tm
left join my_table p
  on month(created_date)=tm.mth
  and year(created_date)=tm.yr
group by yr, mth
order by yr desc, mth desc
```

Result will be

> ```
> count(p.id) | year | month
> ----------: | ---: | ----:
>           0 | 2020 |     6
>           1 | 2020 |     5
>           0 | 2020 |     4
>           0 | 2020 |     3
>           3 | 2020 |     2
>           1 | 2020 |     1
>           0 | 2019 |    12
>           0 | 2019 |    11
>           9 | 2019 |    10
>           0 | 2019 |     9
>           2 | 2019 |     8
>           0 | 2019 |     7
> ```

If you want NULL to be displayed, you could use:

```
with result as (
  select count(p.id) as counter, yr as year, mth as month
  from temp_months tm
  left join my_table p
    on month(created_date)=tm.mth
    and year(created_date)=tm.yr
  group by yr, mth
  order by yr desc, mth desc
)
select
  case when counter = 0 then NULL else counter end as counter,
  year, month
from result;
```

Result will be

> ```
> counter | year | month
> ------: | ---: | ----:
>    null | 2020 |     6
>       1 | 2020 |     5
>    null | 2020 |     4
>    null | 2020 |     3
>       3 | 2020 |     2
>       1 | 2020 |     1
>    null | 2019 |    12
>    null | 2019 |    11
>       9 | 2019 |    10
>    null | 2019 |     9
>       2 | 2019 |     8
>    null | 2019 |     7
> ```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=2ee3594614494d3397a996d7ff815859

To manually but quickly populate temp_months table, I type in a year worth of values like so:

```
insert into temp_table values
(2019, 1), (2019, 2), (2019, 3), (2019, 4), (2019, 5), (2019, 6),
(2019, 7), (2019, 8), (2019, 9), (2019, 10), (2019, 11), (2019, 12);
```

Then, I copy that into a text editor, find/replace 2019 to 2020 and execute again...and so on. Within seconds, I'd have years worth of data in temp_table.

The other option is to create a stored procedure to populate it on demand based on example here: [How to populate a table with a range of dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates)

Comment: That works great, thank you! I didn't think about adding in the years as part of the temporary table. My only other question would be, how could I fill in the temporary table dynamically, say for the past 12 or 24 months?

Comment: If I were you, I'd manually populate it if it was a few years worth of data. You could use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates and modify it to dynamically populate dates using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that will give you results for the last `n` months, using a recursive CTE to generate the year/month combinations for the last `n` months and then `LEFT JOIN`ing those values to `my_table` to get the counts for each year/month combination. This query is set up for the last 12 months (`11` in the recursive part of the CTE), to change to `24` months you would change that value to `23`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
  SELECT MAX(created_date) AS mdate, CONCAT(LEFT(MAX(created_date), 8), '01') AS cdate
  FROM my_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT mdate, cdate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  FROM dates
  WHERE cdate > mdate - INTERVAL 11 MONTH
)
SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS `count`, YEAR(cdate) AS yr, MONTH(cdate) AS mth
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN my_table p ON p.created_date BETWEEN d.cdate AND LAST_DAY(d.cdate)
GROUP BY cdate
ORDER BY cdate DESC
```

Output (for @zedfoxus sample data):

```
count   yr      mth
1       2020    5
0       2020    4
0       2020    3
3       2020    2
1       2020    1
0       2019    12
0       2019    11
9       2019    10
0       2019    9
2       2019    8
0       2019    7
0       2019    6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f44525455c0884461bb02be8cda58f7a)

That query runs from the maximum date in the table, to run from the current date, change the recursive CTE as below:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
  SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 8), '01') AS mdate, CONCAT(LEFT(CURDATE(), 8), '01') AS cdate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT mdate, cdate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  FROM dates
  WHERE cdate > mdate - INTERVAL 11 MONTH
)
SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS `count`, YEAR(cdate) AS yr, MONTH(cdate) AS mth
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN my_table p ON p.created_date BETWEEN d.cdate AND LAST_DAY(d.cdate)
GROUP BY cdate
ORDER BY cdate DESC
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=29e7810521006288228da06cd286dcf5)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MariaDB...

Rather than the messy `UNIONs`, use `seq_0_to_100` and `+ INTERVAL sea MONTH`.