# Value for first available date if no record exisits

Tags: mysql, sql

i have Items table:

```
item_id  |  date       | item_price |
---------+-------------+--------------
1        | 2022-12-05  |     15     |
2        | 2022-02-14  |     12     |
1        | 2022-11-12  |     50     |
4        | 2022-01-21  |     13     |
1        | 2021-12-12  |     10     |
6        | 2021-12-27  |     83     |
```

The query which i use to select price one week ago from today's date:

```
SELECT 
    items.item_id AS id,
    items.item_price AS weekAgoPrice,
    items2.item_price AS monthAgoPrice,
FROM
    items
LEFT JOIN
    items items2 ON items2.item_id = items.item_id
    AND items2.date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
WHERE
    items.item_id = '1'
        AND items.date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

How can i modify query that will return the price from the first available date if there is no entry for a particular date. **Those, if for the specified item_id there is no price 7 days ago, then it should return the value of 6 days ago, if not 6 then 5. Additionally, if there is no price 1 month ago, it should return value of 29 days ago etc.**

Comment: select all records, using the condition `items.date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`, and then order that result by date (ASCENDING, because you seem to want to get the oldest date), and LIMIT it to 1.

Comment: This will work, however i might have some join statements to return prices for different date ranges, i have updated first porst query as an example. Could you advise is it possible to handle it?

Comment: You need start from a calendar table of some kind with a record for each day, and then LEFT JOIN from there to your other data.

Comment: unfortunately, i dont have any calendar table

Comment: There are a number of techniques that enable to generate one on the fly.

Comment: @vehk: Of course it is possible to handle that, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/g5EHQzMM).  but with a [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates), it might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with max window function as the following:

```
With last_prices As
(
  Select *, 
    Max(Case 
         When date Between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) And CURDATE() 
         Then date 
        End) Over (Partition By item_id) As last_price_date_week,
    Max(Case 
         When date Between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) And CURDATE() 
         Then date 
        End) Over (Partition By item_id) As last_price_date_month
  From items
)
Select item_id, date, item_price, 'last week price' As Price_Type
From last_prices
Where item_id = 1 And date = last_price_date_week
Union All
Select item_id, date, item_price, 'last month price' As Price_Type
From last_prices
Where item_id = 1 And date = last_price_date_month
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0q_mjz75).

If you are open to using a stored procedure, you could make this task more dynamic, have a look at this procedure:

```
Create Procedure GetLatesPrice(id INT, period INT, interval_type Varchar(1)) 
Begin
  Select item_id, date, item_price
  From
  (
    Select *, 
      Case 
       When interval_type='d' Then
        Max(
             Case 
               When date Between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL period Day) And CURDATE() 
               Then date 
             End
           ) Over (Partition By item_id)
        When interval_type='m' Then
         Max(
             Case 
               When date Between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL period Month) And CURDATE() 
               Then date 
             End
            ) Over (Partition By item_id)
        When interval_type='d' Then
         Max(
             Case 
               When date Between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL period Year) And CURDATE() 
               Then date 
             End
            ) Over (Partition By item_id)
       End As last_price_date
   From items
  ) T
  Where date = last_price_date And item_id=id;
END
```

And to execute that procedure for example for item_id=1, 15 days ago:

```
Call GetLatesPrice(1, 15, 'd');
-- d for days, m for months, y for years
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ptPrThSl).

Comment: Sorry mate, could you review first post, i have put some updates on it

Comment: Could you edit the question and share the expected output

Comment: Just edited, please review

Comment: So you want two prices, one for a week ago and one for month ago?

Comment: Yep, thats correct. However it may possibly be extended in future to return more prices, 3 month ago, 6 month ago, 1 year  ago etc

Comment: I updated the answer, check and let me know if that is OK with you.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no entry for a particular date, you can use the `COALESCE` function

```
SELECT 
    items.item_id AS id,
    COALESCE(
        items.item_price,
        (SELECT items.item_price FROM items WHERE items.item_id = '1' AND items.date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)),
        (SELECT items.item_price FROM items WHERE items.item_id = '1' AND items.date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)),
        ...
    ) AS price
FROM items
WHERE items.item_id = '1'
```

Comment: So if i will have a range of 100 days from today, i would have to put 100 select queries within coalesce? Is there any chance i can simplify it?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
items.item_id AS id,
COALESCE(
items.item_price,
(SELECT items.item_price FROM items WHERE items.item_id = '1' AND items.date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)),
(SELECT items.item_price FROM items WHERE items.item_id = '1' AND items.date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)),
...
) AS price
FROM items
WHERE items.item_id = '1'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If all you need are scalar values then this would suffice:

```
SET @ItemID = 1;

SELECT (SELECT item_price FROM items WHERE item_id = @ItemID 
    AND date1 >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) order by date1 LIMIT 1) as WeekAgoPrice,
  etc.
```

Also see the [LATERAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) documentation.

Without sample output data it's hard to tell what you intend.