# Get empty row if no record matches mysql in a single table

Tags: sql, mysql, date

```
CREATE TABLE table
 (`id` int, `date` date, `time` time);
INSERT INTO table
  (`id`, `date`, `time`)
 VALUES  
 (1, '2022-05-22', 14:00:00),
 (2, '2022-05-23', 07:35:00),
 (4, '2022-05-23', 14:00:00);
```

Expected Output:

| date | time |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-22 | 14:00:00 |
| 2022-05-22 | NULL |
| 2022-05-23 | 07:35:00 |
| 2022-05-23 | 14:00:00 |

As you notice, there's no entry for 07:35 at date 2022-05-22.

I have tried join on single table and CTE also but nothing works.

I'm using PHP with MySQL

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just insert a fourth null record?

Comment: user can choose any date for any time, we are not asking for null record.

Comment: Do you at least have a range of possible dates/times?

Comment: date will be range of a week and time may vary.

Comment: Update your post with your actual data and query. Attempting to help in semi-blind mode may result in a waste of time for both sides (you and who's helping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A calendar table approach *might* be what you are looking for.  Consider the following select query which however generates the exact output you want.

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2022-05-22' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-05-23'
),
times AS (
    SELECT '07:35:00' AS tm UNION ALL
    SELECT '14:00:00'
)

SELECT d.dt AS date, yt.time
FROM dates d
CROSS JOIN times t
LEFT JOIN yourTable yt
    ON yt.date = d.dt AND
       yt.time = t.tm
ORDER BY d.dt, t.tm;
```

Comment: getting null for all time, https://pasteboard.co/x951iOBC642L.png

Comment: ...then you're not running my code, or else `yourTable` is not what you actually have defined above.

Comment: yes, you are right, I'm trying to filter the result using where and that created the problem.
I have a question regarding hardcoded date and time, can we get rid of hardcoded date and time or at least time?

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132024/how-to-populate-a-table-with-a-range-of-dates

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by @Tim Biegeleisen is working just fine but unfortunately my server doesn't suppoert CTE, so who has little knowledge of CTE or have lower version of mysql can try this solution...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(d.dt) AS date, yt.time
FROM (SELECT date as dt FROM tableName ) as d 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT time as tm FROM tableName ) as t
LEFT JOIN tableName yt
ON yt.date = d.dt AND yt.time = t.tm
ORDER BY d.dt, t.tm;
```